# YouTube views not counting on Wordpress embed

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, embed

On my WordPress site, I have been embedding both my YouTube videos and my Twitch channel.

However, even after using the old embed code which has been suggested on a previous post, no views coming from the site count towards the view count.

As well as this, the official Twitch embed code also does not count towards the view count either.

The code I am using for the site is:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TWH0RnH1QMU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And the twitch:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="250" width="300" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=official_don_gaming" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="allowNetworking" value="all"><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&amp;channel=official_don_gaming&amp;auto_play=true&amp;start_volume=0"></object>
```

Hopefully you can help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's quite a crude solution, simply iframing the url you use when using youtube in your browser should make the views be counted. You can do this with `<iframe src="http://youtubeurl"></iframe>`

Comment: So would you suggest to effectively remove all other information and have: <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWH0RnH1QMU" </iframe>

Comment: That should work, the webpage would be ugly, but it should work. But you have to remove the ";" after the url, it won't work in all browsers else